# rails - Dynamically change view file name on render in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I'm making heavy use of AJAX views. Like the user signup page is a AJAX-requested popup. However this approach isn't SEO friendly as google can't index "popups" and obviously you can't permalink a popup page.

So what I want to do is have a `before_render` like callback where I can dynamically append `.xhr` to my view name if the request is ajax based. It would be good to keep this DRY and not have to code this into every controller.

An example of how this would be done manually is:

```
def new
  render request.xhr? ? 'new.xhr' : 'new'
end
```

Any idea of how this can be achieved without re-writing every single one of my controllers?

Comment: why dont you make use of new.js.erb, it will automatically pick up js.erb for AJAX or JS and new.html.erb for HTML

Comment: because it's HTML content. Not JavaScript content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a solution to this. After tracing the render call I found the easiest way to achieve this was by adding the following to your `ApplicationController`

```
private

  def _process_options options
    options[:template] += '.xhr' if request.xhr?
    super options
  end
```

This works well in Rails 3, in Rails 2 you can achieve something similar by overriding the `default_template_name` method like:

```
private

  def default_template_name
    super + if request.xhr? then '.xhr' else '' end
  end
```